# Python - Cannot call a function from a py file within a class?

Tags: python, function, class, exec

I am trying to call `Myfunction` from a py script and this happens in a Class. But I got an error saying `Myfunction` is not defined. How do I avoid this? I know I can put everything within `file_that_contains_Myfunction_versionA(B).py` into a class and call it in `main()`. But is there other way to  do it?

The trick here is that the name of the function is the same and I can't import the script at the very beginning since I don't know the condition until I run `Myclass()`.

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main()

    def main(self):
            if conditionA:
                exec(open("./file_that_contains_Myfunction_versionA.py").read())
                Myfunction()
            if conditionB:
                exec(open("./file_that_contains_Myfunction_versionB.py").read())
                Myfunction()
```

Comment: `exec` won't modify the local scope. Why are you doing things this way to begin with? Just import it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah that was a simplified code. I edited it a bit to reveal my real situation...

Comment: Again, **you should just import it**

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the other script into the one you're calling it from?

```
from otherscript import function_A

function_A()
```